# OS X says iPhone is full but iOS settings says it has 120GB free

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I am unable to copy files onto my iPhone using OS X because it says the phone is full. As you can see the iPhone Storage page on the device shows 120GB of free space.

[image]

I am trying to fill it with large media files as a work around for the huge backups it is making. My theory is that if I fill it with files it will have to remove any caches of iCloud photos. Then I'll delete the media files and make a smaller backup before the Photos app pulls any more photos down. iCloud is currently saying it as 183GB of photos stored there.

Comment: is there anything else in the waiting line that your MacBook and/or iCloud want(s) to sync?

Comment: @needlol not that I know of. Just this week I bumped my iCloud subscription from 200GB to 2TB as another futile attempt to get around this mess. It's still sitting there at 191GB used

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting it from your iCloud? You could try turning off services before doing a complete logout.

Comment: I turned off iCloud photos, didn't help because it seemed to pull all the photos on to the phone. Then I turned it back and it spent ~20 hours updating them back to iCloud

Comment: @needlol logging out of iCloud altogether is the next step I think. I've no desire to go through that upload process again so it's a last resort if I can't manually cut down the size or figure out someway of flushing all the caches

Comment: it's the 3rd last resort... the 2nd last is to do a full restore and the last is to set up everything from scratch... ohhhh I've been places with that... hope you get it solved before. but don't throw money in their throat needlessly.. cancle the 2tb subscription if not needed 

Comment: I think I solved it by disconnecting iCloud and manually downloading then deleting images via Image Capture. As far as I an see this images should've been 'optimised' to make room for files to be copied on to the device

Comment: Nice. Well done.